# Does a data extension entry event work with decision split?

Tags: journeybuilder, automation, entry-criteria

So my question is much more complicated than the title says.

Case: We want to build a journey which will populate everyone who meet the entry trigger already and for new records entering the journey.

Normally you would use a SQL Query set on overwrite in combination with a automation and use this as entry event. The problem is that i will use a decision split in this journey. My question: will the decision split detect changes in the data using a automation SQL query overwrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario it will not.

Contacts enter to Journey with **static data** where they originate, so with the attributes from your entry Data Extension.

If you later modify the data in the same Data Extension, then upon configuring Decision Split activity via Journey Data path, it will not actually check the Data Extension for the values, but instead use the data your Contact entered the Journey.

In case you need to check for updated values, you will need to have your Data Designer set up in a way to support this requirement via Journey.

- [Journey and Contact Data in Decision Splits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data_decision_splits.htm&type=5)
- [Journey and Contact Data](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data.htm&type=5)